# SQL Left Join Count with Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

Ok so I have two tables: Employee & EmployeeFeedback

[image]

Basically, I need  a list of employees who werent able to take a feedback form in the last 2 weeks in relation to the grouping which is per week (week beginning monday).

Also have a date table available.

Desired output:

[image]

Also doing it for a report in PowerBI, so answers doing this with SQL and/or dax to achieve this would be a great help.

Comment: data in the output is just dummy data

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLServer, tag one of these to get better answer

Comment: good point. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.EMPLOYEEID
    , A.EMPLOYEENAME
    , CASE WHEN C.EMPLOYEEID IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS TakenInPast2Weeks
    , B.START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE
FROM #EMPLOYEE A
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE
    FROM #CALENDAR
    WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -6, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))  AND CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
) B
LEFT JOIN #FEEDBACK C
ON A.EMPLOYEEID = C.EMPLOYEEID
    AND C.DATETAKEN BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -2, START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, START_OF_WEEK_STARTING_MON_DATE)
```